# Response error from a server side. Using TypeORM, react, nextjs, mysql

Tags: mysql, reactjs, next.js, typeorm

I am building a simple registration form and when I post data from the form to server, get a response 200 with error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON" How to fix this problem?

**Here is my code on client side:**

```
"use client";
import axios from "axios";
import { TextField, Button, Grid, Paper, Box, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";

import { useState, ChangeEvent, MouseEvent, FormEventHandler} from 'react';


function Register() {
    const [FormData, setFormData] = useState({
        username: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",

    })
    
    const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const {name,value} = event.target
        setFormData((prevFormData) => ({...prevFormData, [name]: value}))
    }
 const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async(event) => {
     event.preventDefault()
     try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/register/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(FormData),
            
    });
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("User created successfully");
        } else {
            console.error("Something went wrong");
        }
        console.log(FormData)
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
        
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    
     }
 }

    return ( 
           <Box m={2}>
            <Paper style={{padding: 16, margin: 10}}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
  <Grid 
    container direction = "column" 
    spacing={2}
    justifyContent="center"
     alignItems="center">
        <Typography
         variant="h3"
            >
            Registration Form
        </Typography>
        <Grid item>
            <TextField fullWidth 
            label="Username"
            name="username"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            value={FormData.username}
            variant="outlined"
            inputProps={{
                style: { minWidth: '500px' }
            }}
            />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            type="email"
            value={FormData.email}
            variant="outlined"
                        inputProps={{
                            style: { minWidth: '500px' }
                        }}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            type="password"
            value={FormData.password}
            variant="outlined"
                        inputProps={{
                            style: { minWidth: '500px' }
                        }}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Button color="primary" type="submit" variant="contained">
            Register
          </Button>
        </Grid>
       </Grid>
        </form>
        </Paper>
        </Box>
     );
}

export default Register;
```

**Here is my code on server side:**

```
"use client";
import axios from "axios";
import { TextField, Button, Grid, Paper, Box, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";

import { useState, ChangeEvent, MouseEvent, FormEventHandler} from 'react';


function Register() {
    const [FormData, setFormData] = useState({
        username: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",

    })
    
    const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const {name,value} = event.target
        setFormData((prevFormData) => ({...prevFormData, [name]: value}))
    }
 const handleSubmit: FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = async(event) => {
     event.preventDefault()
     try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/register/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(FormData),
            
    });
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log("User created successfully");
        } else {
            console.error("Something went wrong");
        }
        console.log(FormData)
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
        
     } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    
     }
 }

    return ( 
           <Box m={2}>
            <Paper style={{padding: 16, margin: 10}}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
  <Grid 
    container direction = "column" 
    spacing={2}
    justifyContent="center"
     alignItems="center">
        <Typography
         variant="h3"
            >
            Registration Form
        </Typography>
        <Grid item>
            <TextField fullWidth 
            label="Username"
            name="username"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            value={FormData.username}
            variant="outlined"
            inputProps={{
                style: { minWidth: '500px' }
            }}
            />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            type="email"
            value={FormData.email}
            variant="outlined"
                        inputProps={{
                            style: { minWidth: '500px' }
                        }}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            label="Password"
            name="password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            required
            type="password"
            value={FormData.password}
            variant="outlined"
                        inputProps={{
                            style: { minWidth: '500px' }
                        }}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item>
          <Button color="primary" type="submit" variant="contained">
            Register
          </Button>
        </Grid>
       </Grid>
        </form>
        </Paper>
        </Box>
     );
}

export default Register;
```

I can not figure out, why it does not work. Please clue me in right direction.